# Enumerate variadic template parameter pack

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I have `std::vector<val_t>` (`val_t` - my own implementation of `std::any`) which holds arguments for function that I want to call and a parameter pack `Args` that contains types of arguments of that function.

```c++
using arg_pack_t = std::vector<val_t>;

template <typename R, typename... Args>
class function_reflector_t<R (*)(Args...)> {
    typedef R (*c_function_t)(Args...);
    using reflected_t = signature_reflector_t<R, Args...>;

  public:
    static function_metadata_t reflect(std::string name, c_function_t c_function)
    {
        // HERE! 
        universal_wrapper_t invoke = [](arg_pack_t args) -> val_t {
            return args[0].as<c_functon_t>()(args[??? + 1].as<Args>()...);
        };

        return {
            reinterpret_cast<void *>(c_function),
            nullptr,
            invoke,
            std::move(name),
            reflected_t::arguments(),
            reflected_t::return_type(),
        };
    }
};
```

To call this function I need to associate type of argument with index of same argument, so after all template instantiations are done compiler could generate an equivalent code to something like this:

```c++
universal_wrapper_t invoke = [](arg_pack_t args) -> val_t {
            return args[0].as<c_functon_t>()(args[1].as<int>(), args[2].as<double>());
        };
```

I read about `std::integer_sequence` but I couldn't come up with a way of using it in this case.
Ideally I need some template like `std::index_sequence_for` that instead of `size_t` provides a type that has aliases to both index and type at that index, so it behaves kinda like python's `enumerate`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might do somethig like that:

```
template <std::size_t ... Is>
static function_metadata_t reflect(std::string name,
                                   c_function_t c_function,
                                   std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    universal_wrapper_t invoke = [](arg_pack_t args) -> val_t {
        return args[0].as<c_functon_t>()(args[Is + 1].as<Args>()...);
    };

    return {
        reinterpret_cast<void *>(c_function),
        nullptr,
        invoke,
        std::move(name),
        reflected_t::arguments(),
        reflected_t::return_type(),
    };
}

static function_metadata_t reflect(std::string name, c_function_t c_function)
{
    return reflect(name, c_function, std::index_sequence_for<Args...>());
}
```